# Error al rellenar select con datos de una consulta, el dato aparece y desaparece!

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estoy mostrando en un select los cursos en los que no esta inscrito el alumno, esto es para inscribir al alumno en otro curso.

Este select lo relleno a través de una consulta, el problema es que cuando hago clic en agregar curso para que me muestre el formulario con el select que contenga los cursos en los que no esta inscrito ese alumno, el dato en el select al momento de que carga la pagina aparece y desaparece en cuestión de 1 segundo. No da ningún error en consola ni nada. Le he dado vueltas y vueltas pero no logro saber porque.

Dejare el código PHP y JS:

Aqui mi consulta para ver los cursos no inscritos por el estudiante

```
function form_agg_curso_student(){

 $id=$_GET['id_students'];

 $query = "SELECT id,curso FROM cursos_abiertos WHERE cursos_abiertos.id
 NOT IN ( SELECT inscritos.id_curso FROM inscritos WHERE 
 inscritos.id_student = '$id')";
 $sql = $mysqli->query($query);

    <select name="cursos" id="cursos" class="selectpicker form-control">';

    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
      $form.='<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['curso'].'</option>';
    }

    $form.='</select>
  </div>
 </form></div></div></div></div>';
 return $form;
 }
```

Y esta es mi petición con AJAX

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cursos').on('change',function(){
    var id = $("#cursos").val()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'ver_monto.php',
        data:{'id':id}
    })
    .done(function(listas_cursos){
        $("#fecha").val(listas_cursos)
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('error')
    })
  })
 });
```

Como ya les he dicho el dato aparece y desaparece en cuestión de 1 segundo en el select, al que me pueda socorrer con este problema muchas gracias. Vease:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el select que debe listar los cursos, pero el dato aparece y desaparece en cuestion de un segundo

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido a tu primera llamada Ajax, la cual se ejecuta en el  `$(document).ready(function(){` sin estar ligada a ninguna acción. Lo que haces ahí es, cuando el DOM está listo, hacer una petición a Ajax para que te cargue los cursos... ¿Por qué no cargas los cursos directamente desde PHP y dejas sólo la otra llamada a Ajax, o sea esta: `$('#cursos').on('change',function(){...`?

Comment: Cedano he editado la pregunta. Hice lo que me dijiste he eliminado la primera petición AJAX y los he cargado desde PHP, pero me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Solucionado, solo tenia que ordenar unas cosas de los archivos a los que llamaba. Gracias Cedano tu comentario me ha ayudado.

Comment: Me alegro de que hayas encontrado una solución. Saludos.